# Detailed and clear specification for datanucleus jdo extensions?

Tags: datanucleus

I can't find a clear or detailed specification for datanucleus jdo extensions. I suppose that's the page for extensions:
http://www.datanucleus.org/plugins/index.html

Am I correct ? I'm confused because this page is about "plugins", do they mean "extensions" ?!

Now even after opening that page, it looks like you'll have to go through each single link to find what you need. And even when I open sub-page, It's just not helpful at all !

Any information about this topic is very much appreciated, thanks a lot.